# Notepad++ find procedure/ function declaration

Tags: notepad++, regex

I need to find a procedure declaration in Notepad++.
How should I search using regex to find

```
procedure someproc(..)
```

and not the procedure "includes"

```
external procedure someproc(...)
```

i.e., search should ignore search results with preceding "external". "external can be on a separate line (though it is usually on the same)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this gets more and more complicated using Regex, the more general the match should become. If it has to find all code-legal procedure declarations, you'd be better off with a code analyzer library / plugin.

The Regex closest to what you're looking for is:
`(?<!external\s)procedure\s+\w+\(.*?\)`

Please note that this won't work under many circumstances because quantifiers are not allowed in lookarounds under many circumstances.